# Call a web API from lambda given an x509 certification and private key

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-lambda, x509certificate, tls1.2

Im very new to utilizing certs for authenticating API calls and was looking for a means of replicating the behavior of keytool on my local machine for sending a post request to a web API, I have been provided a .pem x509 cert and a .key private key

Ive looked into aws cert manager but im not so sure if it would be able to provide the cert for a lambda job run

What tools would be appropriate for me to handle providing the cert to a lambda job in the aws ecosystem for authenticating a POST rest API call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general words, you describe configuration values, one critically kept *secret*, which the lambda requires.  Put the configuration values into AWS Secrets Manager.  Use the [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html]
(GetSecretValue) SecretsManager API call to pull the secret from within your lambda.  If your lambda runs frequently, cache the API key and secret in memory for later runs to cut down on API calls and runtime.